# Splicing image array (FITS file) using coordinates from header

Tags: python, scipy, fits, astropy

I am trying to splice a fits array based on the latitudes provided from the `Header`. However, I cannot seem to do so with my knowledge of Python and the documentation of `astropy`. The code I have is something like this:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np

Wise1 = fits.open('Image1.fits')
im1 = Wise1[0].data

im1 = np.where(im1 > *latitude1, 0, im1)

newhdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(im1)
newhdulist = fits.HDUList([newhdu])
newhdulist.writeto('1b1_Bg_Removed_2.fits')
```

Here `latitude1` would be a value in degrees, recognized after being called from the header. So there are two things I need to accomplish:

1. How to call the header to recognize Galactic Latitudes?
2. Splice the array in such a way that it only contains values for the range of latitudes, with everything else being 0.

Answer (score 3):

I think by "splice" you mean "cut out" or "crop", based on the example you've shown.

`astropy.nddata` has a [routine for world-coordinate-system-based (i.e., lat/lon or ra/dec) cutouts](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/astropy.nddata.utils.Cutout2D.html)

However, in the simple case you're dealing with, you just need the coordinates of each pixel. Do this by making a WCS:

```
from astropy import wcs
w = wcs.WCS(Wise1[0].header)
xx,yy = np.indices(im.shape)
lon,lat = w.wcs_pix2world(xx,yy,0)

newim = im[lat > my_lowest_latitude]
```

But if you want to preserve the header information, you're much better off using the cutout tool, since you then do not have to manually manage this.

```
from astropy.nddata import Cutout2D
from astropy import coordinates
from astropy import units as u

# example coordinate - you'll have to figure one out that's in your map
center = coordinates.SkyCoord(mylon*u.deg, mylat*u.deg, frame='fk5')

# then make an array cutout
co = nddata.Cutout2D(im, center, size=[0.1,0.2]*u.arcmin, wcs=w)

# create a new FITS HDU
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(data=co.data, header=co.wcs.to_header())

# write to disk
hdu.writeto('cropped_file.fits')
```

An example use case is in the [astropy documentation](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nddata/utils.html#d-cutout-from-a-skycoord-position).

Comment: Currently the coutout tool "Cutout2D" is not available if I'm correct, so how would I maintain the header information?